# Magento Get Product Collection Filter By Store Id

Tags: php, magento

Both stores have a different root category. Main Store is the default sample data, Second Store has just one product I was added. I would have thought that using the store filter, only products within the root category of the current store would show up. But I'm getting every product showing. I'm testing this by placing the following in my category view template:

```
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->addStoreFilter($store_id)
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();
foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){ 
echo $this->htmlEscape($_testproduct->getName()); 
};
```

If I print the store ID, it's giving me the correct number. I have only one product in second Store , so why am I getting every product from all stores returned? I can set every product in Main Store to not show in Store2 and then add a visibility filter, but that would take forever.

Also, I just noticed, if I echo the products store ID, I get the current ID, not the store it's assigned to:

```
echo $_testproduct->getStoreId()
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this You get as you want

```
$counter = "";
/*$model=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($post['stores']);
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore($post['stores'])->getRootCategoryId();
$products = $model->getCollection();
$products->addStoreFilter($post['stores']);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('nlike' => 'B%'));
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
$counter=$products->getData();*/
$model=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($post['stores']);
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore($post['stores'])->getRootCategoryId();
$_category = $category_model->load($rootCategoryId);
$all_child_categories = $category_model->getResource()->getAllChildren($_category);
foreach($all_child_categories as $storecategories):

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($storecategories);
$products = $category->getProductCollection();
//echo "Category id is::".$storecategories."Products are::".count($products);
//echo "<br/>";
foreach($products as $collection):
   $removecatindex = $collection->getData();
   unset($removecatindex['cat_index_position']);
   $counter[] = $removecatindex;
  endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also try adding a store filter to the resource model like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId())
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($store_id)
->addAttributeToSelect('*') // select all attributes
->setPageSize(5000) // limit number of results returned
->setCurPage(1); // set the offset (useful for pagination)

// we iterate through the list of products to get attribute values
foreach ($collection as $product) {
  echo $product->getName(); //get name
  echo (float) $product->getPrice(); //get price as cast to float
  echo $product->getDescription(); //get description
  echo $product->getShortDescription(); //get short description
  echo $product->getTypeId(); //get product type
  echo $product->getStatus(); //get product status

  // getCategoryIds(); returns an array of category IDs associated with the product
  foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $category_id) {
      $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
      echo $category->getName();
      echo $category->getParentCategory()->getName(); // get parent of category
  }
  //gets the image url of the product
  echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).
      'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();
  echo $product->getSpecialPrice();
  echo $product->getProductUrl();  //gets the product url
  echo '<br />';
}
```